# Goto a tab without using anchor links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the Scroll Javascript and have found the problem with the tabs, which is that it is conflicting with the scroll javascript. i.e.

```
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">menu1 </a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu2 </a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu3</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Is it possible to link to tabs without using the anchor? (#menu1)

Kind Regards,

Comment: Yes, but for accessibility reasons i would advise against it.

Comment: change the scroll code to ignore anything inside the `nav-tabs`. Need to see scroll code used

Comment: think you should be able to use data-target at this point

Answer (score 8):

You can use `data-target` attribute instead:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a data-target="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">First Tab</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a data-target="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Second Tab</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">Content 1</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">Content 2</div>
</div>
```

Here is a [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10204/)

Comment: Couldn't get this to work - I think the JQuery I use is conflicting with this also

Comment: this is the source I use - <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'></script> I can see that fiddle working

Comment: I am using Bootstrap tabs, but when I use that source for another part of the page, it conflicts

Answer (score 0):

Appears so:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul class="super">
        <li><a>title 1</a></li>
        <li><a>title 2 </a></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        content1
    </div>
    <div>
        content2
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs ul.super li a").each(function (index) {
            $(this).attr("href", "#spec" + index.toString());            
        });
        $("#tabs div").each(function (index) {
            $(this).attr("id", "spec" + index.toString());
        })
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });      
</script>
```

Source: [is it possible to use Tabs without using anchor tag and id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032703/is-it-posible-to-use-tabs-without-using-anchor-tag-and-id)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the following line from

> var d = $("#scroller-anchor").offset({scroll:false}).top;

to

> var d = $("#scroller-anchor").offset().top;